# How can I script a 'shutdown -r 1' and return an exit status?

Tags: php, bash, shell, exit

I am writing a program that will at some point call a shell script. I need this shell script (bash, or if necessary PHP 4+ will work) to be called by the program, and return an exit status that I can relay before the 1 minute is reached and the system reboots.

Here's an idea of what I mean, best as I can describe:

- Program calls 'reboot' script
- Reboot script runs 'shutdown -r 1' and then exits with a status of 0
- Program echo's out the exit status
- Server reboots

I can get everything to work except the exit status - no matter what I try the program never exits its loop waiting for an exit status, so it never returns anything but the reboot still occurs. This program runs other scripts that return exit statuses, so I need this one to as well to maintain functionality and all that...

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**- The program that calls the reboot script is a PHP script that runs in a loop. When certain events happen, the program runs certain scripts and echos out the exit status. All of them work but this - it never returns an exit status.

Scripts are being called using system($cmd) where $cmd is './scriptname.sh'

Comment: are you sure it's the script being called that's the problem?

Comment: Well as far as I can tell, anyways. I don't have any issues with other scripts that the program calls, it captures and echos the exit statuses normally. Just this one script that fails :(

Comment: try turning on shell debugging any place you have a shell script? `set -vx` ? Then you can see what is executing a completing and what is executing but not completing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're opening the process using proc_open, then calling proc_get_status should return an array that has the exit code in it.

Comment: I edited the question to further explain how the program works and scripts are called. Thank you for your input! I am researching proc_open as a possible alternative, but that means tons of extra coding work :(

Comment: Are you passing the optional second parameter to system() to get the return status?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bash script that backgrounds the shutdown process:

```
#!/bin/bash
shutdown -r 1 &
exit 0
```

This returns control to the parent shell, which receives "0" as the exit code.

Comment: That's how I tried it, and it didn't return an exit status...also tried similar in PHP to no avail. :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't rely on PHP's **system()** and **exec()** functions to retrieve the proper return value, but with a nice little workaround in **BASH**, it's possible to parse exit code really effectively:

```
function runthis($command) {
  $output = array();
  $retcode = -1;
  $command .= " &2>1; echo $?";

  exec($command, $output, $retcode);
  $retcode = intval(array_pop($output));

  return $retcode;
}

if (runthis("shutdown -r 1") !== 0) echo "Command failed!\n";
```

Let me break down what does the code doing:

- `$command .= " &2>1; echo $?";` - expand the command so we pipe the stderr into stdout, then run `echo $?`
- `echo $?` - this special bash parameter which expands to the last executed command's exit code.
- `exec($command, $output, $retcode);` - execute the command. ($retcode is just a placeholder here since the returned data isn't trustworthy. We'll overwrite it later.) The command's output will be written in $output as an array. Every element will represent an individual row.
- `$retcode = intval(array_pop($output));` - parse the last row as an integer. (since the last command will be `echo $?`, it will be always the actual exitcode.

And that's all you need! Although it's a really crude code, and prone to errors if not used correctly, it's perfect for executing simpler tasks, and it will always give you the proper exit code.

For more professional (and programmatic) approach, you have to dig yourself into PHP's **pnctl**, **posix**, **stream** functions, and also **Linux pipe** handling.